# How to use vundle for vim installed from AUR

Tags: plugin-vundle, linux-arch

I'm in a process of completely switching to `vim` for my development purposes. In order to make it more IDE-like I want to install a couple of plugins and I decided to use `vundle` as a plugin manager.

As I'm using Arch Linux the first thing I did was installing `vundle` from AUR using `yaourt`. The problem I encountered is that it installs all the `vundle` stuff somewhere in `/usr/share/vim/` folder (I run `sudo find / -name autoload` to actually locate `vundle` specific directories). But according to `vundle` [Git repo](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) it should be located in `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`.

Then in `.vimrc` file I have to add bunch of lines including `set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` to make `vundle` work. But I can't locate this file at all and I have no idea how to make it work with a `vundle` installed with `yaourt`.

Yep, and the reason I want to install `vundle` in that particular way is in order to get this package automatically updated.

Any thoughts on how to make things work?

P.S. I searched this Stack site and did not managed to find any similar question so I do believe it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so after some investigation I finally located a `vundle` file. It start from a lower-cased letter and that's why I did not find it at the first place.

It's located in `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/vundle.vim` folder. To make `vundle` work with such a setup, the following tweaks to a config from `vundle` [repo](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) are necessary:

```
...
set rtp+=/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/autoload/vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/vundle.vim'
...
call vundle#end()
```

Then place your plugins in place of second three dots (`...`). Then running `PluginInstall` from `vim` all the added plugins will be install in `~/.vim/bundle/` folder.